# Livecode back button

Tags: livecode, hypercard

I am just new in livecode. I created a back button and added below code on `on mouseup` event. I put the back button inside the `Card 5`. On `Card 1`, I have code that will go to `Card 5`.

The problem is, when I press the back button in Card 5, it always goes to `Card 4`. Is this the correct behavior? I was thinking if it should goes to `Card 1` which is the previous card. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
go to the previous card
```

Cards:

```
Card 1
Card 2
Card 3
Card 4
Card 5
```

UPDATE:

I have managed to fix my own problem. I created a global variable to store the previous card name and use this line of code `go to card "previous card name"`. But if anybody else have better solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **recent** keyword will do what you are looking for. Each time you navigate to a card it is added to the 'recent' list, so…

```
go to the recent card
```

…will step back through the recently visited cards, much like the back button on a browser.

This can be shortened to…

```
go recent
```

Then to move forward again through the 'recent' list, use…

go forward

Note that both forward and recent cycle through the recent list, so if the list only contains 1, 2 & 3 then when you go forward and reach card 3, the next forward command  will take you to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Or just use

```
go back
```

Going to the "previous" or the "next" card will take you to the previous or next card in the sequence that they've been stored in, which is why you ended at card 4 from card 5.